# How to display RecyclerView Header like Google Play Store with no External Libraries - Kotlin

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview, view

## About

Im making a mockup app that can display a Header inside of `RecyclerView` that has the same style as Google Play Store.

The Header will have :

1. `TextView` located at the top left that displays the *ActivityName*
2. `ImageButton` located at the top right centered with the *ActivityName* that inflates another Activity
3. `SeachView` located at the bottom of both the `TextView` and `ImageButton`
4. A Tag section that will replace the contents/items of the `RecyclerView` (I also don't know what is the terminology or the best View/Container to use)

### The Problem

I'm trying to learn how to use getItemViewType or how to insert all the (4)views I want in RecyclerView Adapter. I have already looked through numerous tutorials and articles, but sadly there is no clear tutorial that teaches the "Normal" way of making a Header inside of RecyclerView that requires no external dependencies.

It would be a big help if someone could show me a clear article/ tutorial/ way in Kotlin that can solve my problem that uses no External Libraries.

#### The App

1. Youtube video to how my Header would act in RecyclerView [Header video link](https://youtu.be/n_mrrva_zUM)
2. Header Reference [Google Play Store Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlWMr.jpg)
3. Desired Header [Desired App Header Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0LwG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for it can be done pretty easily with the new [ConcatAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ConcatAdapter):

```
        val adapterList = mutableListOf<RecyclerView.Adapter<*>>()
                .apply {
                    add(HeaderAdapter())
                    add(TitleAdapter("Items"))
                    add(ItemsAdapter())
                    add(TitleAdapter("Crates"))
                    add(CratesAdapter()) 
                }

        adapter = ConcatAdapter(adapterList)
```

A suggested alternative format:

```
        adapter = ConcatAdapter(
                    HeaderAdapter(),
                    TitleAdapter("Items"),
                    ItemsAdapter(),
                    TitleAdapter("Crates"),
                    CratesAdapter())
```

*Notice that `adapter` is referring to yours RecyclerView's variable.*

For `TitleAdapter` and `HeaderAdapter`, you just create an adapter with `getItemCount() = 1` and your desired view in its ViewHolder.

Comment: Although this might give me insight with my tag problem. I think this wont act as i would expect it to be.

Comment: Please watch the youtube video provided in the link.

Comment: I did watch the video before answering, and now as well. I fail understand what the problem is or why this won't work. Can you elaborate? If there's something confusing you I can clarify it even further.

Comment: Will ConcatAdapter be able to follow the scroll motion as shown here in the link?

[gif](https://miro.medium.com/max/550/1*ACoGxbjIoQsrQS6OBrh1vQ.gif)

Comment: my concern is, is this method possible when implementing a header and a footer for the app. at the same time being able to change the views with a tag.