# How to add a default static item at the top in a RecyclerView in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I wanted to have an item always appear at the top in the `RecyclerView`. I am fetching data from the `Firestore` and displaying them in a `RecyclerView`. What I want is an item to appear at the top of the list and then show the items which are fetched from the `Firestore`. How can I do this?

Following is my adapter.

```
open class CategoryListAdapter(private val context: Context, private var list: ArrayList<Categories>)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private var onClickListener: OnClickListener? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(
            BottomsheetCategoryListLayoutBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(
                    parent.context
                ), parent, false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val model = list[position]

        if (holder is MyViewHolder) {

            GlideLoader(context).loadPicture(model.category_image, holder.binding.ivCategoryImage)
            holder.binding.tvCategoryName.text=model.category_name
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            if (onClickListener != null) {
                onClickListener!!.onClick(position, model)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    fun setOnClickListener(onClickListener: OnClickListener) {
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener
    }

    interface OnClickListener{
        fun onClick(position: Int, category: Categories)
    }

    private class MyViewHolder(val binding: BottomsheetCategoryListLayoutBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

}
```

Comment: It is possible with Multiple View Types in the adapter. you can look at this https://blog.mindorks.com/recyclerview-multiple-view-types-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConcatAdapter as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63528030/506796).

Or you can create an Adapter that handles multiple types of rows. I prefer doing it this way, because it has the flexibility to have sub headers that can move around into different positions in the list.

Create a sealed interface to represent either type of row item (header, or your Categories class).

```
sealed interface CategoriesListItem

// For now we can use a singleton object. If you have non-static data 
// to be placed in the header, you'll need a class so you can hold that 
// data and bind it in `onBindViewHolder`.
object: CategoriesHeader: CategoriesListItem

// Your existing Categories class, now implementing the sealed interface:
data class Categories(/*...*/): CategoriesListItem
```

Make your List type `<CategoriesListItem>` instead of `<Categories>`, and put the `CategoriesHeader` as the first item in your list.

*Currently it looks like you are using a single mutable list in your adapter. I recommend switching to ListAdapter, where you call `submitList` with a fresh new List instance each time there is a change, and it efficiently animates the change for you. When you make this switch, you'll need to include `CategoriesHeader` as the first item in each list.*

In your adapter, override `getItemViewType()` and you can distinguish between the two types of rows using constant Ints. `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder` should be updated to handle which type of row is being created/bound.

```
class CategoryListAdapter(private val context: Context, private var list: ArrayList<CategoriesListItem>)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    companion object {
        const val VIEW_TYPE_HEADER = 0
        const val VIEW_TYPE_CATEGORIES = 1
    }

    private var onClickListener: OnClickListener? = null

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = when (list[position) {
        CategoriesHeader -> VIEW_TYPE_HEADER 
        is Categories -> VIEW_TYPE_CATEGORIES 
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder = when (viewType) {
        VIEW_TYPE_HEADER -> MyHeaderViewHolder( /* ... */ )
        VIEW_TYPE_CATEGORIES -> MyViewHolder(
            BottomsheetCategoryListLayoutBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(
                    parent.context
                ), parent, false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val viewType = getItemViewType(position)
        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_HEADER) {
            return // assuming there's no specific data to put in the header
        }
 
        val model = list[position]
        
        if (holder is MyViewHolder) {

            GlideLoader(context).loadPicture(model.category_image, holder.binding.ivCategoryImage)
            holder.binding.tvCategoryName.text=model.category_name
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            if (onClickListener != null) {
                onClickListener!!.onClick(position, model)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    fun setOnClickListener(onClickListener: OnClickListener) {
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener
    }

    interface OnClickListener{
        fun onClick(position: Int, category: Categories)
    }

    private class MyHeaderViewHolder(val binding: SomeHeaderViewBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    private class MyViewHolder(val binding: BottomsheetCategoryListLayoutBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

}
```